# Mini mock server for rspec without rails

Tags: ruby, rspec, minitest, end-to-end

I would like to test an API client in rspec.

I'm currently mocking Typhoeus - but I wondered if there is a more end-to-end way of doing this. Essentially, what I would like is something like:

```
it "makes a connection to the server" do
  MockServer.new do |server|
    subject.url = server.url
    subject.run!

    expect(server.last_request.params).to eq({some: "params"})
    expect(server.last_request.headers).to include({"X-whatty-what" => "yepyep"})
  end
end
```

Maybe I could do this with Sinatra, or even rack directly... Anybody done something like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stub the requests using [Webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock).

It is recommended to stub every request you expect to make separately so you know exactly what is requested, but you can also use a syntax similar to what you asked for.

```
it "makes a connection to the server" do
  stub_request(:any, "www.example.com")

  subject.url = "www.example.com"
  subject.run!

  expect(
    a_request(:post, "www.example.com").with(
      body: { some: "params" },
      headers: { "X-whatty-what" => "yepyep" }
    )
  ).to have_been_made
end
```

The webmock docs have plenty of good examples, take a look.